# syntax of {search-query} for search in OneDrive

Tags: onedrive

OneDrive API defines end point for search
GET /me/drive/root/search(q='{search-query}')
But there is no information for syntax of search-query.

What does "{search-query}" have to be for search file with name "One'Two"?
Request
GET /me/drive/root/search(q='One\'Two')
returns error

Request
GET /me/drive/root/search(q='One''Two')
return both One'Two and One!Two

What does "{search-query}" have to be for search string "What?" in file content?
Request
GET /me/drive/root/search(q='What?')
returns error

In both cases description of error was "Bad Request - Error in query syntax."

Comment: How can we help you when you don't show us what error?

Comment: Error was "Bad Request - Error in query syntax."

Comment: Then [edit] your question to reflect that